# WPF Datagrid for IList<String> - cannot add new values

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, mvvm-light

I have a JSON model and on there an IList subordinates.

Nothing special and I wanted to put them into a datagrid where users can add and remove values from that list.

So first I hit the only length column problem because apparently C# finds it funny to pick the properties and that happens to be length.

So I got around that by another stackoverflow explaining this.

```
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Job.Subordinates, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll="True" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"  Height="Auto" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Grid.Column="1" AutoGenerateColumns="False" >
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Subordinate Id">
            <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding}"></TextBlock>
                </DataTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        </DataGridTemplateColumn>
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

However now the end result is a read only DataGrid.  I can't add new rows or edit an existing row if I load in a JSON.

Why would this behavior be happening ?

edit: the json object with its field

```
using GalaSoft.MvvmLight;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace GalaxyCreator.Model.Json
{
    public class Job : ObservableObject
    {
        private String _id;
        public String Id
        {
            get { return _id; }
            set
            {
                Set(ref _id, value);
            }
        }

        private String _name;
        public String Name
        {
            get { return _name; }
            set
            {
                Set(ref _name, value);
            }
        }

        private Boolean _startActive;
        public Boolean StartActive
        {
            get { return _startActive; }
            set
            {
                Set(ref _startActive, value);
            }
        }

        private Boolean _disabled;
        public Boolean Disabled
        {
            get { return _disabled; }
            set
            {
                Set(ref _disabled, value);
            }
        }

        private Boolean _rebuild;
        public Boolean Rebuild
        {
            get { return _rebuild; }
            set
            {
                Set(ref _rebuild, value);
            }
        }

        private Boolean _comandeerable;
        public Boolean Commandeerable
        {
            get { return _comandeerable; }
            set
            {
                Set(ref _comandeerable, value);
            }
        }

        private Boolean _subordinate;
        public Boolean Subordinate
        {
            get { return _subordinate; }
            set
            {
                Set(ref _subordinate, value);
            }
        }

        private bool _buildatshipyard = true;
        public bool Buildatshipyard
        {
            get { return _buildatshipyard; }
            set
            {
                Set(ref _buildatshipyard, value);
            }
        }

        private JobLocation _jobLocation = new JobLocation();
        public JobLocation JobLocation
        {
            get { return _jobLocation; }
            set
            {
                Set(ref _jobLocation, value);
            }
        }

        private JobCategory _jobCategory = new JobCategory();
        public JobCategory JobCategory
        {
            get { return _jobCategory; }
            set
            {
                Set(ref _jobCategory, value);
            }
        }

        private JobQuota _jobQuota = new JobQuota();
        public JobQuota JobQuota
        {
            get { return _jobQuota; }
            set
            {
                Set(ref _jobQuota, value);
            }
        }

        private IList<JobOrder> _orders = new List<JobOrder>();
        public IList<JobOrder> Orders
        {
            get { return _orders; }
            set
            {
                Set(ref _orders, value);
            }
        }

        private String _basket;
        public String Basket
        {
            get { return _basket; }
            set
            {
                Set(ref _basket, value);
            }
        }

        private String _encounters;
        public String Encounters
        {
            get { return _encounters; }
            set
            {
                Set(ref _encounters, value);
            }
        }

        private String _time;
        public String Time
        {
            get { return _time; }
            set
            {
                Set(ref _time, value);
            }
        }
        private Ship _ship = new Ship();
        public Ship Ship
        {
            get { return _ship; }
            set
            {
                Set(ref _ship, value);
            }
        }

        private IList<String> _subordinates = new List<String>();
        public IList<String> Subordinates
        {
            get { return _subordinates; }
            set
            {
                Set(ref _subordinates, value);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

edit: I tried a new approach but still no luck, this time I tried wrapping the String

Wrapper

```
public class SubordinateItem : ObservableObject
{
    private String _value = default(String);

    public SubordinateItem(string subordinate)
    {
        this._value = subordinate;
    }

    public String Value
    {
        get { return _value; }
        set
        {
            if (value != _value)
            {
                _value = value;
                Set(ref _value, value);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

ViewModel

```
class JobEditorDetailViewModel : DialogViewModelBase
{
    public Job Job { get; set; }

    private ObservableCollection<SubordinateItem> _subordinateItems = new ObservableCollection<SubordinateItem>();
    public ObservableCollection<SubordinateItem> SubordinateItems
    {
        get { return _subordinateItems; }
        set
        {                
            this.Job.Subordinates.Clear();
            foreach (SubordinateItem item in value)
            {
                this.Job.Subordinates.Add(item.Value);
            }
            Set(ref _subordinateItems, value);
        }
    }

    public JobEditorDetailViewModel(string message, Job job) : base(message)
    {
        this.Job = job;
        this._saveCommand = new RelayCommand<object>((parent) => OnSaveClicked(parent));
        this._cancelCommand = new RelayCommand<object>((parent) => OnCancelClicked(parent));
        foreach(String subordinate in Job.Subordinates)
        {
            _subordinateItems.Add(new SubordinateItem(subordinate));
        }
    }
}
```

XAML

```
                <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding SubordinateItems, NotifyOnTargetUpdated=True}" ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll="True" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" 
                          ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" Height="Auto" Grid.Row="1" AutoGenerateColumns="False" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="572" >
                    <DataGrid.Columns>
                        <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Value, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Width="500" Header="Subordinate Id" IsReadOnly="false" />
                    </DataGrid.Columns>
                </DataGrid>
```

Comment: What field do you bind to? `Text="{Binding}"` means binding to *whole* object.

Comment: I'll add the json object for clarity, but this is what how that other stackoverflow post said I could work around the "only length property shown"..  I just realised I forgot to mention this is using MVVM light as framework

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after a long session on writing all kinds of hacks to try and fix it I got a solution with the following setup

```
public class SubordinateItem : ObservableObject
{
    private String _value = default(String);

    public SubordinateItem() { }

    public SubordinateItem(string subordinate)
    {
        this._value = subordinate;
    }

    public String Value
    {
        get { return _value; }
        set
        {
            if (value != _value)
            {
                _value = value;
                Set(ref _value, value);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Notice the public constructor without params, this is needed to be able to add new items to the datagrid.  Without it, it cannot instantiate new objects for it.  Here is the view model

```
class JobEditorDetailViewModel : DialogViewModelBase
{
    public Job Job { get; set; }

    private RelayCommand<object> _saveCommand = null;
    public RelayCommand<object> SaveCommand
    {
        get { return _saveCommand; }
        set { _saveCommand = value; }
    }

    private RelayCommand<object> _cancelCommand = null;
    public RelayCommand<object> CancelCommand
    {
        get { return _cancelCommand; }
        set { _cancelCommand = value; }
    }

    private IList<SubordinateItem> _subordinateItems = new List<SubordinateItem>();
    public IList<SubordinateItem> SubordinateItems
    {
        get { return _subordinateItems; }
        set
        {
            Set(ref _subordinateItems, value);
        }
    }

    public JobEditorDetailViewModel(string message, Job job) : base(message)
    {
        this.Job = job;
        this._saveCommand = new RelayCommand<object>((parent) => OnSaveClicked(parent));
        this._cancelCommand = new RelayCommand<object>((parent) => OnCancelClicked(parent));
        foreach (String subordinate in Job.Subordinates)
        {
            _subordinateItems.Add(new SubordinateItem(subordinate));
        }
    }

    private void OnSaveClicked(object parameter)
    {
        this.Job.Subordinates.Clear();
        foreach (SubordinateItem item in _subordinateItems)
        {
            this.Job.Subordinates.Add(item.Value);
        }
        this.CloseDialogWithResult(parameter as Window, DialogResult.Yes);
    }

    private void OnCancelClicked(object parameter)
    {
        this.CloseDialogWithResult(parameter as Window, DialogResult.No);
    }
}
```

So in the constructor of the viewmodel I take the data from the json object Job.Subordinates which is an IList of String and I wrap it in SubordinateItem and store it in _subordinateItems.  The datagrid is bound to this and will work with it.  Then I have a save button with a command behind it where I do the reverse.  I take everything the DataGrid has in _subordinateItems and put it back into the json object.  There was no way whatsoever it seemed for me to bind the datagrid directly to the json object IList of String

The Xaml relevant part

```
                <Label Content="Subordinates" />
                <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding SubordinateItems, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" 
                          ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll="True" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" 
                          ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" 
                          Height="Auto" Grid.Row="1" 
                          AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
                          HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
                          Width="572" SelectionMode="Single">
                    <DataGrid.Columns>
                        <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Value, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Width="500" Header="Subordinate Id" IsReadOnly="false" />
                    </DataGrid.Columns>
                </DataGrid>
```